# Populate Trello cards with website - HTML forms

Tags: trello

I use Trello a lot to manage my clients needs and the tasks associated with each one. However, it's becoming difficult to enter in all of their information each time I obtain a new client (I get new clients regularly).

It would be ideal if I can use form input from my website to populate new client cards.

Is there any way to do that or anything with similar efficiency?

Comment: You can program in your server's backend scripting language (Python, PHP, or Node.js, or whatever) a small utility using Trello API to post new cards.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I'd never known it was even possible. Can you give me an idea of how I can use the API to actually add a card, for example in PHP?

Comment: On StackOverflow, search for trello and PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125384/trello-api-create-new-card-out-of-php-code

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Trello Power-Ups handling forms for Trello now, [Blue Cat Forms](https://trello.com/power-ups/6139de588901011c01baf52f/forms-by-blue-cat) recently launched has the tightest integration with Trello in that it supports Trello Custom Fields as well as the standard Card fields.

You can create a Form linked to a specific Trello Board. Cards created will have all their data populated from the Form, including the ability to add attachments and etc.